# Bug in MSVC compiler? Clang and GCC don't complain. Testing for valid operator in compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, compiler-bug

So consider the following:

Used for convenience (plus C++17 "support"):

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;

template<bool B>
using bool_constant = std::integral_constant<bool, B>;
```

Then we have the main stuff:

```
//is_post_incrementable
template<typename, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_post_incrementable : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_post_incrementable<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>()++)>> : std::true_type {};

//is_pre_incrementable
template<typename, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_pre_incrementable : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_pre_incrementable<T, void_t<decltype(++std::declval<T&>())>> : std::true_type {};

//is_incrementable
template<typename T>
struct is_incrementable : bool_constant<is_pre_incrementable<T>::value
                                     || is_post_incrementable<T>::value> {};
```

We apply some tests on:

```
struct foo { int a = 2; };
struct foo2 { int a = 2; foo2& operator++() { ++a; return *this; } };
struct foo3 { int a = 2; foo3 operator++(int) { foo3 temp(*this); ++a; return *this; } };

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_pre_incrementable<foo>::value; //0
    std::cout << is_pre_incrementable<foo2>::value; //0 - should be 1
    std::cout << is_pre_incrementable<foo3>::value; //1 - should be 0
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << is_post_incrementable<foo>::value; //0
    std::cout << is_post_incrementable<foo2>::value; //0
    std::cout << is_post_incrementable<foo3>::value; //1
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << is_incrementable<foo>::value; //0
    std::cout << is_incrementable<foo2>::value; //0 - should be 1
    std::cout << is_incrementable<foo3>::value; //1
}
```

Those are the results I get in MVSC. The weird thing is this: If I move `is_pre_increment` over `is_post_increment` in the code, instead of `001 001 001`, I get `010 010 010`. It still isn't the desired `010 001 011` result.

Clang and GCC produce the expected result though.

**LIVE example(Clang):** http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f9c72b2a2e851b8

**LIVE example(GCC):** http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beed9f24eedd4d61

Is there a logic error on my part, or is it a plain MSVC bug?

Comment: MSVC doesn't completely support expression SFINAE, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/12/02/partial-support-for-expression-sfinae-in-vs-2015-update-1.aspx).

Comment: @Praetorian Well that is just too unfortunate. Not easy writing a library in Visual Studio...

Comment: According to that blog post, using a dependent decltype in a partial specialization is actually supported in VS2015 update 1, but MSVC seems to have issues when you get `void_t` involved (this is possibly related to their unsupported scenario #2). If you use `decltype(void(std::declval<T&>()++))` (and likewise for pre-increment), it works correctly.